# Calculating difference between two dates with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to display the difference between the 1st of October 2013 and today.

According to Microsoft's calculator date difference tool it is 274 days.

But with my current javascript code, I get a result of 244 days.

My current code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var pregnant = new Date(2013, 10, 1) 
    today=new Date()
    var one_day=1000*60*60*24

    var difference =  Math.ceil((today.getTime()-pregnant.getTime())/(one_day));

    document.write("It has been " + difference + " days since Jackie has been pregnant!")

</script>
```

Also I need some help with placing the content in a specific div rather than just throwing it in the html somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months are zero based, so october would be the ninth month in javascript, not the tenth.

```
var pregnant = new Date(2013, 9, 1);
```

To put the result in an element, you do something like

```
document.querySelector('element_id').innerHTML = "It has been " + difference + " ....";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know this.
One extra small question though: How do I output the result of this within a specific div in my html?
Now with document.write it gets a random position.

Comment: Just saw your edit, trying that now!

Comment: I have 
document.querySelector('#days') and also <div id="days"></div>
However it  is not working :/

Comment: Place the javascript at the bottom, right before `</body>`